# Can't submit multiple step form with yup validations and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I am having troubles with react-hook-form and yup, I need to create a multistep form (there are many other inputs but I just leave a few to give you an example), so!
the stepper works fine until the finish step, when I click "Register" (last step, should submit) it shows the following error:

[image]

here is my code:

```
const RegisterClient = props => {
  const [currStep, setCurrStep] = React.useState(1)

      const schema1 = Yup.object().shape({
        // company
        company_name: Yup.string().required("Name required"),
        email: Yup.string().email().required("Email required"),
        password: Yup.string()
          .matches(
            passwordRules,
            "Password must contain at least 8 digits (one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and a symbol)."
          )
          .required("Required"),
      })
    
      const scheme2 = Yup.object().shape({
        // representative
        representative_name: Yup.string().required(
          "Representative name is required"
        ),
        representative_email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Representative email required"),
      })

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(currStep === 1 ? schema1 : currStep === 2 && scheme2),
    defaultValues: {
      company_name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      representative_name: "",
      representative_email: "",
    },
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(errors)
  }, [errors])

  function stepper() {
    const steps = {
      1: <Step1 control={control} errors={errors} />,
      2: <Step2 control={control} errors={errors} />,
      3: <FinalStep control={control} errors={errors} />,
    }
    return steps[currStep]
  }

  function previousStep() {
    console.log("previous...")
    if (currStep === 1) return
    setCurrStep(curr => curr - 1)
  }

  function nextStep() {
    console.log("next: ", getValues())
    setCurrStep(curr => curr + 1)
    return
  }

  const onSubmit = async user => {
    if (currStep < 3) nextStep()
    else {
      console.log("user: ", user)
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

        {stepper()}

        <div className="mt-3 d-flex gap-4 justify-content-between">
          <Button
            outline
            color="dark"
            type="button"
            onClick={previousStep}
            disabled={currStep === 1}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button color="primary">
            {loading ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                Loading... <Spinner size="sm">Loading...</Spinner>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : currStep === 3 ? (
              "Register"
            ) : (
              "Next"
            )}
          </Button>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-4 text-center">
          <p className="mb-0">
            By registering you agree to the Skote{" "}
            <Link to="#" className="text-primary">
              Terms of Use
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default RegisterClient

function Step1({ control, errors }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="company_name">Company Name</Label>
        <Controller
          name="company_name"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input
              {...field}
              placeholder="Company Name"
              type="text"
              invalid={Boolean(errors.company_name)}
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors.company_name && (
          <FormFeedback>{errors.company_name?.message}</FormFeedback>
        )}
      </FormGroup>

      <Row>
        <Col sm="12" md="6" lg="6" xl="6">
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="email">Email</Label>
            <Controller
              name="email"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  type="email"
                  invalid={Boolean(errors.email)}
                />
              )}
            />
            {errors.email && (
              <FormFeedback>{errors.email?.message}</FormFeedback>
            )}
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="12" md="6" lg="6" xl="6">
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="password">Password</Label>
            <Controller
              name="password"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  invalid={Boolean(errors.password)}
                />
              )}
            />
            {errors.password && (
              <FormFeedback>{errors.password?.message}</FormFeedback>
            )}
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

function Step2({ control, errors }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="representative_name">Representative name</Label>
        <Controller
          name="representative_name"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input
              {...field}
              placeholder="Representative name"
              type="text"
              invalid={Boolean(errors.representative_name)}
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors.representative_name && (
          <FormFeedback>{errors.representative_name?.message}</FormFeedback>
        )}
      </FormGroup>

      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="representative_email">Representative email</Label>
        <Controller
          name="representative_email"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input
              {...field}
              placeholder="Representative email"
              type="text"
              invalid={Boolean(errors.representative_email)}
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors.representative_email && (
          <FormFeedback>{errors.representative_email?.message}</FormFeedback>
        )}
      </FormGroup>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

function FinalStep() {
  return <h2>This is the final step...</h2>
}
```

My second option is to have a single schema like this:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
   company: Yup.object().shape({
        // company
        company_name: Yup.string().required("Name required"),
        email: Yup.string().email().required("Email required"),
        password: Yup.string()
          .matches(
            passwordRules,
            "Password must contain at least 8 digits (one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and a symbol)."
          )
          .required("Required"),
      }),
   representative: Yup.object().shape({
        // representative
        representative_name: Yup.string().required(
          "Representative name is required"
        ),
        representative_email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Representative email required"),
      })
})
```

but in this case, I have no idea how to make react-hook-form check for the specific schema inside the main one, am I explain?

I need help please :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not the guy who just wait for responses... I already figure it out, so here's my solution if someone has the same issue in the future:

```
  const schema = [
    Yup.object().shape({
      // company
      company_name: Yup.string().required("Name required"),
      description: Yup.string().required("Description required"),
      phone: Yup.string().required("Phone required"),
      email: Yup.string().email().required("Email required"),
      validateEmail: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Please confirm your email")
        .oneOf([Yup.ref("email")], "Email do not match"),
      password: Yup.string()
        .matches(
          passwordRules,
          "Password must contain at least 8 digits (one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and a symbol)."
        )
        .required("Required"),
      validatePassword: Yup.string()
        .required("Please confirm your password")
        .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Passwords do not match"),
    }),
    Yup.object().shape({
      // representative
      representative_name: Yup.string().required(
        "Representative name is required"
      ),
      representative_position: Yup.string().required(
        "Representative position is required"
      ),
      representative_email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Representative email required"),
      representative_phone: Yup.string().required("Phone required"),
    }),
    Yup.object().shape({
      line_business: Yup.string().required(),
      status: Yup.string().required(),
      user_type: Yup.string().required(),
    }),
  ]

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema[currStep - 1]), // this is because my steps start with 1, and the schema array start with position 0
    defaultValues: {
      company_name: "",
      description: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      validateEmail: "",
      password: "",
      validatePassword: "",
      representative_name: "",
      representative_position: "",
      representative_email: "",
      representative_phone: "",
      line_business: "1",
      status: "2",
      user_type: userType,
    },
  })
```

**NOTICE:** that in my case, the last object in the schema array check validation for values that I have defined with default values because I don't need to change those, I think that if you just add any validation without the .required() should work as well ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

If Any one get the same error when using formik, use `schema[currStep - 1]` in the validationSchema prop as well.